# Bulk Api parent child relation

Tags: bulk-api

i am trying to use Bulk Api to create a case. Case object contains Account,other custom child objects and Account contains Contact. How can i insert/update/upsert this object structure using BulkApi in CSV and JSON format

Comment: If you're creating "a" Case (as in one), why are you using the Bulk API? The REST API would be much more suitable, and you could make use of the [sObject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm#!) resource.

Comment: just to test Bulk Api , i am trying to create one Case but the requirement is i will get large amount of data from external system to create cases

Answer (score 1):

You have to upsert the parent objects first, and the Bulk Api will return the new IDs. Then you have to map the old IDs to the new IDs in the child objects, and use the Bulk API to upsert them as well. Nothing magic about it, unfortunately.